# SQL add conversion of date to existing query

Tags: sql, sql-server

I'm would like to convert the date using this function. I'm using SQL server 2014

```
CONVERT(varchar, sc.StartDate,103) + '" + " " + "' + '" + " - " + "' + CONVERT(varchar, sc.EndDate,103) SIPDate
```

so it will display in dd/mm/yyyy - dd/mm/yyyy. How do i add it into the query? Thanks.

The query is:

```
SELECT CONCAT(sc.StartDate, sc.ENDDate) SIPDate,
   COUNT (sj.LOComment) WeekReviewed,
   COUNT(sjd.WeekNo) TotalWeek,
   SUM(sjj.TotalDaysRecord) TotalDaysRecord,
   COUNT(CASE sjd.JournalStatusCode WHEN 'D' THEN 1 ELSE NULL END) PENDingComplete
FROM StudentJournalDate sjd
LEFT JOIN StudentJournal sj
    ON sjd.WeekNo = sj.WeekNo
LEFT OUTER JOIN
(
    SELECT sj.WeekNo, 
           CASE WHEN RTRIM(sj.Day1Journal) = '' OR sj.Day1Journal IS NULL THEN 0 ELSE 1 END +
           CASE WHEN RTRIM(sj.Day2Journal) = '' OR sj.Day2Journal IS NULL THEN 0 ELSE 1 END +
           CASE WHEN RTRIM(sj.Day3Journal) = '' OR sj.Day3Journal IS NULL THEN 0 ELSE 1 END +
           CASE WHEN RTRIM(sj.Day4Journal) = '' OR sj.Day4Journal IS NULL THEN 0 ELSE 1 END +
           CASE WHEN RTRIM(sj.Day5Journal) = '' OR sj.Day5Journal IS NULL THEN 0 ELSE 1 END +
           CASE WHEN RTRIM(sj.Day6Journal) = '' OR sj.Day6Journal IS NULL THEN 0 ELSE 1 END +
           CASE WHEN RTRIM(sj.Day7Journal) = '' OR sj.Day7Journal IS NULL THEN 0 ELSE 1 END AS TotalDaysRecord 
    FROM StudentJournal sj
) AS sjj
    ON sjj.WeekNo = sj.WeekNo
LEFT OUTER JOIN StudentSIP sc
    ON sc.AdminNo = sjd.AdminNo
GROUP BY CONCAT(sc.StartDate, sc.ENDDate)
```

Comment: Hello again, I gave you another answer below.  If you don't like that, we might be able to wrap your query as a subquery and format the date on the outside.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can just `SELECT` and `GROUP BY` this formatted date expression, i.e.:

```
SELECT CONVERT(varchar, sc.StartDate, 103) + " - " + CONVERT(varchar, sc.EndDate, 103) AS SIPDate,
       COUNT (sj.LOComment) WeekReviewed,
       COUNT(sjd.WeekNo) TotalWeek,
       SUM(sjj.TotalDaysRecord) TotalDaysRecord,
       COUNT(CASE sjd.JournalStatusCode WHEN 'D' THEN 1 ELSE NULL END) PENDingComplete
FROM StudentJournalDate sjd
LEFT JOIN StudentJournal sj
    ON sjd.WeekNo = sj.WeekNo
LEFT OUTER JOIN
(
    SELECT sj.WeekNo, 
           CASE WHEN RTRIM(sj.Day1Journal) = '' OR sj.Day1Journal IS NULL THEN 0 ELSE 1 END +
           CASE WHEN RTRIM(sj.Day2Journal) = '' OR sj.Day2Journal IS NULL THEN 0 ELSE 1 END +
           CASE WHEN RTRIM(sj.Day3Journal) = '' OR sj.Day3Journal IS NULL THEN 0 ELSE 1 END +
           CASE WHEN RTRIM(sj.Day4Journal) = '' OR sj.Day4Journal IS NULL THEN 0 ELSE 1 END +
           CASE WHEN RTRIM(sj.Day5Journal) = '' OR sj.Day5Journal IS NULL THEN 0 ELSE 1 END +
           CASE WHEN RTRIM(sj.Day6Journal) = '' OR sj.Day6Journal IS NULL THEN 0 ELSE 1 END +
           CASE WHEN RTRIM(sj.Day7Journal) = '' OR sj.Day7Journal IS NULL THEN 0 ELSE 1 END AS TotalDaysRecord 
    FROM StudentJournal sj
) AS sjj
    ON sjj.WeekNo = sj.WeekNo
LEFT OUTER JOIN StudentSIP sc
    ON sc.AdminNo = sjd.AdminNo
GROUP BY CONVERT(varchar, sc.StartDate, 103) + " - " + CONVERT(varchar, sc.EndDate, 103)
```

Comment: OP's expression looks odd, it should probably be something like this; CONVERT(varchar, sc.StartDate,103) + ' - ' + CONVERT(varchar, sc.EndDate,103)

Comment: @RichBenner Yes, it looked strange, and the SO markdown was colored incorrectly also indicating a problem.  I have updated my answer, thanks.

Comment: Hi, thanks for helping. I've encounter these error when i run the query Msg 102, Level 15, State 1, Line 2
Incorrect syntax near 'COUNT'.
Msg 156, Level 15, State 1, Line 20
Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'AS'.

Comment: @user3807187 Sorry, the first term in the `SELECT` was missing a comma.  Reload the page.

Comment: Thank you. I have to use this + '" + " " + "' + '" + " - " + "' + instead of + " - " + to get it to display the format i want. Weird. Nevertheless, it works.

Answer (score 1):

Try this. since your SQL SERVER is 2014 you can use format to format the date

```
SELECT     CONCAT(FORMAT(sc.StartDate,'dd/MM/yyy'),+ ' - ' +FORMAT(sc.ENDDate,'dd/MM/yyy'))  SIPDate,
   COUNT (sj.LOComment) WeekReviewed,
   COUNT(sjd.WeekNo) TotalWeek,
   SUM(sjj.TotalDaysRecord) TotalDaysRecord,
   COUNT(CASE sjd.JournalStatusCode WHEN 'D' THEN 1 ELSE NULL END) PENDingComplete
FROM StudentJournalDate sjd
LEFT JOIN StudentJournal sj
    ON sjd.WeekNo = sj.WeekNo
LEFT OUTER JOIN
(
    SELECT sj.WeekNo, 
           CASE WHEN RTRIM(sj.Day1Journal) = '' OR sj.Day1Journal IS NULL THEN 0 ELSE 1 END +
           CASE WHEN RTRIM(sj.Day2Journal) = '' OR sj.Day2Journal IS NULL THEN 0 ELSE 1 END +
           CASE WHEN RTRIM(sj.Day3Journal) = '' OR sj.Day3Journal IS NULL THEN 0 ELSE 1 END +
           CASE WHEN RTRIM(sj.Day4Journal) = '' OR sj.Day4Journal IS NULL THEN 0 ELSE 1 END +
           CASE WHEN RTRIM(sj.Day5Journal) = '' OR sj.Day5Journal IS NULL THEN 0 ELSE 1 END +
           CASE WHEN RTRIM(sj.Day6Journal) = '' OR sj.Day6Journal IS NULL THEN 0 ELSE 1 END +
           CASE WHEN RTRIM(sj.Day7Journal) = '' OR sj.Day7Journal IS NULL THEN 0 ELSE 1 END AS TotalDaysRecord 
    FROM StudentJournal sj
) AS sjj
    ON sjj.WeekNo = sj.WeekNo
LEFT OUTER JOIN StudentSIP sc
    ON sc.AdminNo = sjd.AdminNo
GROUP BY CONCAT(FORMAT(sc.StartDate,'dd/MM/yyy'),+ ' - ' +FORMAT(sc.ENDDate,'dd/MM/yyy'))
```

Comment: Hi, thanks for the help. I encounter this error when i run the query.                    Msg 164, Level 15, State 1, Line 26
Each GROUP BY expression must contain at least one column that is not an outer reference.

Comment: @user3807187 i have edited the query. run it again and let me know if you have error

Comment: Hi, your query works too. But @Tim Biegeleisen provide the query sooner.  So i have to give him the upvote. Thanks :)